# Fill In The Date Gaps With Date Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

I have two tables.

An orders table with customer, and date.
A date dimension table from a data warehouse.

The orders table does not contain activity for every date in a given month, but I need to return a result set that fills in the gaps with date and customer.

**For Example, I need this:**

```
Customer   Date
===============================
Cust1       1/15/2012   
Cust1       1/18/2012
Cust2       1/5/2012
Cust2       1/8/2012
```

**To look like this:**

```
Customer   Date
============================
Cust1       1/15/2012   
Cust1       1/16/2012   
Cust1       1/17/2012       
Cust1       1/18/2012
Cust2       1/5/2012
Cust2       1/6/2012
Cust2       1/7/2012
Cust2       1/8/2012
```

This seems like a left outer join, but it is not returning the expected results.
Here is what I am using, but this is not returning every date from the date table as expected.

```
SELECT o.customer, 
       d.fulldate
FROM   datetable d 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o 
                    ON d.fulldate = o.orderdate 
WHERE  d.calendaryear IN ( 2012 );
```

Comment: Is the gap filling per customer? so if Cust1 and Cust2 have a gap on the same days, do we fill per customer? Your sample data does not show this

Comment: The output has the customer, but the date that is showing up is only the dates found in the orders table.  Where i expect to see the all dates from the date table

Comment: Dates in the date table that have no order date should show up customer null in that query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you need all customers for all dates.  When you do the `left outer join`, you are getting NULL for the customer field.

The following sets up a driver table by `cross join`ing the customer names and dates:

```
SELECT driver.customer, driver.fulldate, o.amount 
FROM   (select d.fulldate, customer
        from datetable d cross join
             (select customer
              from orders
              where year(orderdate) in (2012)
             ) o
        where d.calendaryear IN ( 2012 )
       ) driver LEFT OUTER JOIN
       orders o 
       ON driver.fulldate = o.orderdate and
          driver.customer = o.customer;
```

Note that this version assumes that `calendaryear` is the same as `year(orderdate)`.

Comment: Thank you, this got me headed in the right direction for sure!

Answer (score 6):

You can use recursive CTE to get all dates between two dates without need for `datetable`:

```
;WITH CTE_MinMax AS
(
    SELECT Customer, MIN(DATE) AS MinDate, MAX(DATE) AS MaxDate
    FROM dbo.orders
    GROUP BY Customer
)
,CTE_Dates AS
(
    SELECT Customer, MinDate AS Date
    FROM CTE_MinMax
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Customer, DATEADD(DD,1,Date) FROM CTE_Dates c
    INNER JOIN CTE_MinMax mm ON c.Customer = mm.Customer
    WHERE DATEADD(DD,1,Date) <= mm.MaxDate
)
SELECT c.* , COALESCE(o.Amount, 0)
FROM CTE_Dates c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.Customer = o.Customer AND c.Date = o.Date
ORDER BY Customer, Date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db2de/1)**

Comment: Recursive CTE can be very slow if the date range gets large. Why not use a numbers table, a calendar table, or a system table if neither of those exists? You might find [this blog series](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
SELECT  A.Customer,
        B.fulldate [Date],
        ISNULL(C.Amount,0) Amount
FROM (  SELECT  Customer, 
                MIN([Date]) MinDate,
                MAX([Date]) MaxDate
        FROM Orders
        GROUP BY Customer) A
LEFT JOIN DateTable B
    ON B.fulldate BETWEEN A.MinDate AND A.MaxDate
LEFT JOIN Orders C
    ON A.Customer = C.Customer 
    AND B.fulldate = C.[Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that datetable includes every date of the year you can do with one simple CTE

```
WITH OrdersCustomerDateBorders AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID, MIN(fulldate) AS FirstOrderDate, MAX(fulldate) AS LastOrderDate
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customer
)
select o.customer, d.fulldate, ISNULL(o.amount, 0) AS Amount
from orders o
INNER JOIN OrdersCustomerDateBorders OCDB ON OCDB.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN datetable d ON  ON d.fulldate between OCDB.FirstOrderDate AND OCDB.LastOrderDate
WHERE d.calendaryear in (2012);
```