# Given *multiple partitions* what is a better way to fill all the date gaps with calendar table?

Tags: sql

The task is to find and fill missing year and it's avg_id for every Make. Make is dynamic and can't be hardcoded.

Given this calendar table:

```
avg_year, avg_id
2011    , 1     
2012    , 2     
2013    , 3     
2014    , 4     
2015    , 14    
2016    , 15    
2017    , 16    
2010    , 5     
2009    , 6     
2008    , 7
```

And this data with gaps:

```
car_year, car_id, make         
2011    , 51    , 'BMW'        
2012    , 24    , 'BMW'        
2013    , 37    , 'BMW'        
2014    , 52    , 'BMW'        
2011    , 78    , 'Mitsubishi' 
2012    , 80    , 'Mitsubish'  
2014    , 99    , 'Mitsubishi' 
2008    , 101   , 'Audi'       
2008    , 102   , 'Audi'       
2013    , 102   , 'Audi'       
2015    , 103   , 'Audi'
```

What is a better way to get this data:

```
CAR_YEAR,CAR_ID,MAKE       ,AVG_ID
2008    ,101   ,Audi       ,7     
2008    ,102   ,Audi       ,7     
2009    ,null  ,Audi       ,6     
2010    ,null  ,Audi       ,5     
2011    ,null  ,Audi       ,1     
2012    ,null  ,Audi       ,2     
2013    ,102   ,Audi       ,3     
2014    ,null  ,Audi       ,4     
2015    ,103   ,Audi       ,14    
2016    ,null  ,Audi       ,15    
2017    ,null  ,Audi       ,16    
2008    ,null  ,BMW        ,7     
2009    ,null  ,BMW        ,6     
2010    ,null  ,BMW        ,5     
2011    ,51    ,BMW        ,1     
2012    ,24    ,BMW        ,2     
2013    ,37    ,BMW        ,3     
2014    ,52    ,BMW        ,4     
2015    ,null  ,BMW        ,14    
2016    ,null  ,BMW        ,15    
2017    ,null  ,BMW        ,16    
2008    ,null  ,Mitsubishi ,7     
2009    ,null  ,Mitsubishi ,6     
2010    ,null  ,Mitsubishi ,5     
2011    ,78    ,Mitsubishi ,1     
2012    ,null  ,Mitsubishi ,2     
2013    ,null  ,Mitsubishi ,3     
2014    ,99    ,Mitsubishi ,4     
2015    ,null  ,Mitsubishi ,14    
2016    ,null  ,Mitsubishi ,15    
2017    ,null  ,Mitsubishi ,16
```

In the [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/raw/uVeqx3w2) there is a solution for this issue.

The question is not "how" but "how to do it better".

Bonus kudos if the solution is not Vendor-specific. (i.e. lack of connect by ... level)

Similar question: [fill-in-the-date-gaps-with-date-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451230/fill-in-the-date-gaps-with-date-table)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The task is DBMS-agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the data you want:

```
select m.make, c.car_year, g.car_id, c.avg_id
from calendar c cross join
     (select distinct make from gaps) m left join
     gaps g
     on g.make = m.make and g.avg_year = c.car_year
order by m.make, c.car_year;
```