# SQLite: Group data within certain time interval

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a single table which stores data of orders:

Orders Table:

```
id | order_time          | quantity | ...
1  | 1592821854318       | 2
2  | 1592901538199       | 4
3  | 1592966454547       | 1
4  | 1593081282406       | 9
5  | 1593141826330       | 6
```

order_time table is UNIX timestamp.

Using below query I am able to get available data grouped by days (86400000 = 24 hours):

```
 SELECT order_time+ (86400000 - (order_time % 86400000)) as gap, SUM(quantity) as 
            totalOrdersBetweenInterval
    FROM USAGE_DETAILS ud 
                WHERE order_time >= 1590969600 AND order_time <= 1593388799000 
          
GROUP BY gap 
ORDER BY gap ASC
```

Suppose for this month of June, I receive order on 1, 4, 6, 7 date then by using above query I am able to retrieve data as follow :

```
gap | totalOrdersBetweenInterval 
1   | 5
4   | 6
6   | 4
7   | 10
```

I would receive UNIX timestamp in gap column but for the sake of example I have used readable dates.

Above query will only retrieve data for the days which would have received order but I want to split data in range like below which also include days with no orders :

```
gap | totalOrdersBetweenInterval 
1   | 5
2   | 0
3   | 0
4   | 6
5   | 0
6   | 4
7   | 10
8   | 0
9   | 0
.   | .
.   | .
```

How do I go about that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451230/fill-in-the-date-gaps-with-date-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a query that returns 30 rows:1,2,...,30 for the days of June.
You could do it with a recursive `CTE`:

```
with days as (
  select 1 day
  union all
  select day + 1
  from days
  where day < 30
)
```

but I'm not sure if Android uses a version of SQLite that supports `CTE`s.

If it does support them, all you need to do is join the `CTE` with a `LEFT` join to your query:

```
with 
  days as (
    select 1 day
    union all
    select day + 1
    from days
    where day < 30
  ),
  yourquery as (
    <your query here>
  )
select d.day, coalesce(t.totalOrdersBetweenInterval, 0) totalOrdersBetweenInterval
from days d left join yourquery t
on t.gap = d.day
```

If Android does not support `CTE`s you will have to build the query that returns the days with `UNION ALL`:

```
select d.day, coalesce(t.totalOrdersBetweenInterval, 0) totalOrdersBetweenInterval
from (
  select 1 day union all select 2 union all
  select 3 union all select 4 union all
  ......................................
  select 29 union all select 30
) d left join (
  <your query here>
) t
on t.gap = d.day
```

Comment: Your query worked, but there is one problem with my dataset. 
Since days/gap is in unix timestamp since epoch I am getting data from beginning of epoch time.
What I did was replace (day < 30) to (day < 1593388799000) and select (day + 1) to (day + 86400000) equivalent to 1 day. 
Doing this I am getting records from beginning of epoch.
And if I try to limit days to month like (where day > 1590969600000 and day < 1593388799000)
I am getting 0 records. Any idea about that?

Comment: day                    |     totalOrdersBetweenInterval
1                        |     0
86400001          |     0
172800001        |     0
   .                      |     .
   .                      |     .
   .                      |     .
1593043200001|     3
 1593129600001|    5

Comment: I figured it out. 
I had to also change (Select 1 day) to unix time equivalent of my starting month which is (select 1590969600000 day) for June month.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to @forpas for helping me out.**
Just posting in case someone is searching for slicing data by unix time intervals.

```
with 
  days as (
    select 1590969600000 day    --Starting of June 1 2020 
    union all
    select day + 86400000       --equivalent to 1 day 
    from days
    where day < 1593388799000   --Less than 28th of June
  ),
  subquery as (
    SELECT order_time+ (86400000 - (order_time % 86400000)) as gap, SUM(quantity) as 
            totalOrdersBetweenInterval
    FROM USAGE_DETAILS ud 
                WHERE order_time >= 1590969600000 AND order_time <= 1593388799000 
          
    GROUP BY gap 
  )
select d.day, coalesce(t.totalOrdersBetweenInterval, 0) totalOrdersBetweenInterval
from days d left join subquery t
on t.gap = d.day
order by d.day
```